# Have Gmail display messages inside the list

Tags: gmail

Not sure how to word this, but I'd quite like Gmail to work like Google Reader - where you can just k,k,k up through the messages, without switching out to 'another page' for each message.

I guess it's not possible - haven't seen anything in Labs that looks like I want - but has this already been asked for? Just interested to know if there's some place I can go and vote!

Answer (score 2):

No, there is nothing in Labs, though people have requested it.  There are a couple alternative options with keyboard shortcuts.

You can use `j` to move down and `k` to move up the message list in your inbox.  (You mentioned you knew `k` already).  However, these also work when viewing a message.  If you are viewing a message, hit `k` to read your next newest email.

If you prefer working from the inbox list each time, `o` will open the current email, and `u` returns you to the listing.

Comment: I know it isn't exactly what you asked for, but what you want isn't currently possible, so maybe this helps a little?

Answer (score 0):

There is. <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> page through conversations.

<kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd> page through messages in a conversation. You can open/collapse messages with <kbd>o</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You can see the available keyboard shortcuts in Gmail by hitting <kbd>?</kbd>.